# Javascript responseText

Tags: javascript

How to load an page instead of http.responseText

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = http.responseText; // works
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = "test"; // works
 document.getElementById("content3").src = "dir/file.txt;"; // how display file.txt content.
```

the file.txt path is at the same location as javascript. [web sever]

Comment: you want to load the contents of a file with javascript?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you trying to load a local file? A file from the server?

Comment: Yes. i want load file content in to the page. if  http.responseText = false or by error.

Comment: Where is "file.txt" - on the webserver, or the user's computer?

Comment: I don't get it? If you want content from a file in a DIV, you need to make another AJAX request (XLMHttpRequest). You have obviously done this already (with http.responseText) - and this is the ONLY way you can do it, unless you create an IFRAME, load the content file into it and then copy it, but that would just be silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you could just do:

```
$("#element").load("file.txt");
```

All you need to do is download the jQuery js file and put it on your webserver, then include it at the top of your page:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

...this is assuming your file is server side. It's not possible if it's a client-side file you want

Comment: sorry but this not what want.

Comment: No problems - you still haven't clarified whether you are trying to load a file from the user's machine (client) or the webserver

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that through JavaScript directly, you'll have to do it server-side...

Comment: Yes this is correct - browsers can't access files on the client machine

Comment: yes i know that, and im not trying to access the client machine