# display html content in div

Tags: javascript

How to display html content

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceContent(show) {

         var display = new Array();
         display[1] = 1.html;
         display[2] = 2.html; 

         document.getElementById("ShowItems").innerHTML = display[show];

    }
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="replaceContent(1)">1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="replaceContent(2)">2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="replaceContent(3)">3</a>
    <div id="ShowItems">...</div>
```

thankyou.

Comment: You've already asked the same question (phrased differently) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065121/javascript-responsetext

You would be better off asking for this question to be closed and concentrating on explaining things better in the other question....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to populate #ShowItems with the contents of 1.html, 2.html, etc?  This doesn't make very much sense, unless 1.html and 2.html are really just page fragments.  Consider iframes.

Answer (score 0):

wha?

try `display[1] = "<b>Content 1</b>";` ie it is HTML already.

maybe i don't understand your question...

also arrays are zero indexed so you should start at 0-2 instead of 1-3.

Comment: "Content 1" should be an html file. but if i change display[1] = "Content 1";  to display[1] = Content 1.html;  it wont work.

Comment: oh, yeah that won't work. you should edit your question to be more clear, as you never mention you want to open content from additional files!